# Translate a python dict into a Solr query string

Tags: python, django, solr

I'm just getting started with Python, and I'm stuck on the syntax that I need to convert a set of request.POST parameters to Solr's query syntax.

The use case is a form defined like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField()
    metadata = forms.CharField()
    figures = forms.CharField()
```

Upon submission, the form needs to generate a url-encoded string to pass to a URL client that looks like this:

```
text:myKeyword1+AND+metadata:myKeyword2+AND+figures:myKeyword3
```

Seems like there should be a simple way to do this.  The closest I can get is

```
for f, v in request.POST.iteritems():
   if v:
       qstring += u'%s\u003A%s+and+' % (f,v)
```

However in that case the colon (\u003A) generates a Solr error because it is not getting encoded properly.

What is the clean way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a function in the form to handle this rather than in the view.  So after you call form.isValid() to ensure the data is acceptable.  You can invoke a form.generateSolrQuery() (or whatever name you would like).

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
  text = forms.CharField()
  metadata = forms.CharField()
  figures = forms.CharField()

  def generateSolrQuery(self):
    return "+and+".join(["%s\u003A%s" % (f,v) for f,v in self.cleaned_data.items()])
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks!  Just to note, I think that newer versions of python use "cleaned_data" instead of "clean_data".  Not sure if that is accurate though.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `u'\u003A'` simply the same as `u':'`, which is escaped in URLs as `%3A` ?

```
qstring = '+AND+'.join(
    [ u'%s%%3A%s'%(f,v) for f,v in request.POST.iteritems() if f]
    )
```

Comment: But urlencode builds a string like text=myKeyword1&metadata=myKeyword2. This isn't the syntax that I need (see above).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). It takes care of all the interfacing with Solr - both indexing and querying.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out.  I'm already using Solrpy, which seems nice and lightweight for my purpose.